# Regular expression for decimals from 1 to 9 , or 10 without floating

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-inputmask

I have an html field that need to restrict the user input to either type number from 1 to 9 with a precision of two numbers, or just the number 10, so that the number 10 could not have a precision.
for exp : 5.50  ,7 , 6.45 ,  10  // tolerated numbers
10.5 , 20, 15     //not tolerated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `/^([0-9]([.][0-9]{0,2})?)|10$/`

Comment: Tnx a lot its working, btw I removed the slashes from the beginning and the end.

Comment: @DeepakKumarTP you could make your comment as an answer so that I mentien it as the right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

`^(([1-9]([.][0-9]{1,2})?)|10)$`

Comment: Are you sure this matches the OP's requirements? [https://regex101.com/r/ENfCQa/1](https://regex101.com/r/ENfCQa/2) "need to restrict the user input to either type number from 1 to 9 .."

Comment: Doesn't this still match a leading zero? [https://regex101.com/r/RoRxbE/1](https://regex101.com/r/RoRxbE/1)

Comment: changed the 0 in the first [0-9] to 1, gives [1-9] and voilaaa

Comment: Yes, but "with a precision of two numbers". Your regex still matches `6.4` or `6.` [https://regex101.com/r/7dCY5r/1/](https://regex101.com/r/7dCY5r/1/)

Answer (score 5):

You could do it like this:

[`^([1-9](?:\.\d\d)?|10)$`](https://regex101.com/r/xzTTWv/1)

**Explanation**

- From the beginning of the string `^`
- Match a digit between 1 and 9 `[1-9]`
- A optional non capturing group which matches a dot and 2 digits `(?:\.\d\d)?`
- or match `10`
- Assert the end of the string `$`

Answer (score 1):

What about this ?

> ^([1-9]{1}(\.\d{1,2})?|10)$

Comment: Are you sure this matches the OP's requirement? [https://regex101.com/r/hI6oMi/2](https://regex101.com/r/hI6oMi/2) or [https://regex101.com/r/B749su/1](https://regex101.com/r/B749su/1)

Comment: "with a precision of two numbers" This would still match `4.6` (https://regex101.com/r/oVlvz5/1)[https://regex101.com/r/oVlvz5/1]

Comment: I know what you mean. But if 7 is axcepted why not 4.6 ?

Comment: " with a precision of two numbers" and "10.5 , 20, 15 //not tolerated."